# Are lmer-coefficients standardized or not?

Tags: r, lme4, coefficients, standardized, multilevel-analysis

I have a very basic question; maybe a bit too basic to find a helpful response googeling it.

I am calcultating multi-level-models using the lmer function using this code:

```
lmer(H1_rirs, data= df_long_cl, REML = T)
```

Am I right in assuming that the retrieved coefficients are unstandardized? If yes, is there an easy way to standardize them?

Best,

Carolin

Comment: How is `H1_rirs` defined?

Comment: Hi Roland, it is defined like this: `H1_rirs<-commresc ~ 1 + cvar1c + (1 + cvar1c | ID_new) `    both variables are person-mean-centred, although I guess I should not mean-centre my outcome (it functions as a mediator in the bigger model)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by default, no standardizing is applied.
If you like to get standardized coefficients, one way would be to standardize the data before fitting your model. There is a robust implementation of such a function in the [**effectsize**-package](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/standardize.html). Or you can do some post-hoc standardization (also [effectsize-package](https://easystats.github.io/effectsize/reference/standardize_parameters.html)). The latter yields different results, the most accurate would be standardizing the data before model fitting.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what @daniel suggested with the `effectsize` package, there is also the "pseudo-standardized" coefficient (Hoffman, 2015) where the response and the predictor are standardized based on the level of prediction:

```r
library(lme4)

m <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

effectsize::standardize_parameters(m, method = "pseudo")
#> # Standardization method: pseudo
#> 
#> Parameter   | Coefficient (std.) |       95% CI
#> -----------------------------------------------
#> (Intercept) |               0.00 | [0.00, 0.00]
#> Days        |               0.68 | [0.48, 0.88]
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>